# Android Studio shortcut to edit resource folder values at one place

Tags: android, android-studio

I find it very cumbersome when it comes to changing values in different folders in Resource directory of the project. For example, I have to separately open dimens files for every folder like values-hdpi, values-w640dp, values-w720dp, etc to make changes. Is there any Android Studio shortcut where I could edit values of a particular dimen name in different folders at one place? Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

rename resource file by Shift+F6 (Refactor ->Rename)

**Update :**

you cant change all values at single edit.this is only possible when you create value

for example :

when you have not created any value you just write value in code like

@dimen/title_size

then IDE will show error place cursor there and hit Alt+Enter which will give you hint to create resource where you can select folders in which values need to be generated

Comment: I don't want to rename resource file or dimen name. I'm looking for a way to change their values for all folders(values-hdpi, values-w640dp, values-w720dp, etc) at one place.

Comment: Response to Update: I know that already, when Android Studio asks to create resource for different folders, and where we tick from the available folders. I'm looking for exactly that kind of solution to my problem where a dialog is displayed for a particular resource and I could edit values for different folders. Anyway, that's sad. We could have saved some time if we knew or are provided with a feature how to edit values at one place.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this through Google:
You can use **find in path** *(cmd/ctrl + shift + F)* and search for the key of your resource.

You will get a list of occurrences, where the bottom preview window is **editable**.
It's not perfect, but this way you have everything in one dialog and don't need to open each file separately.

You can also use this for other resources such as strings and colors.

**Tip:** Add leading and trailing characters to filter out all other usages.
For example search for: *="activity_vertical_margin">*

Example:
[image: Preview of find in path dialog]